# How to add markers and polylines to a Leaflet map from a SQLite database or Flask app.py

Tags: sqlite, flask, leaflet

I've tried so much stuff but it's just not happening... this is what I currently have:

app.py:

```
...
@app.route("/paraderos")
def paraderos():
    query1 = "SELECT latitud, longitud from paradero"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    resultado = cursor.execute(query1)
    resultado = resultado.fetchall()
    paraderos_json = json.dumps(resultado)
    return render_template("mapazo.html", paraderos = paraderos_json)
...
```

mapazo.html:

```
...
var paraderos = JSON.parse('{{ paraderos | tojson }}');

for (var i = 0; i < paraderos.length; i++) {
var paradero = paraderos[i];
var marker = L.marker([paradero[0], paradero[1]]).addTo(map_init);
}
...
```

also this is how my database table looks like:

**ID     Latitud     Longitud**
1   -40.5725    -73.1353
2   -40.57395   -73.13348

so "resultado" looks like this `[(-40.5725, -73.1353), (-40.57395, -73.13348)]`

I also tried shoving the data in another URL, which worked, and then querying it with Ajax, that didn't work:

```
@app.route('/paraderos')
def paraderos():
    query1 = "SELECT latitud, longitud from paradero"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    resultado = cursor.execute(query1)
    resultado = resultado.fetchall()

    return jsonify(resultado)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('mapazo.html')
```

```
fetch('/paraderos')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(paraderos => {
    for (var i = 0; i < paraderos.length; i++) {
       var paradero = paraderos[i];
       var marker = L.marker([paradero[0], paradero[1]]).addTo(map_init);
   }
})
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

I'd be very thankful if anyone knows how to fix this or any other better way to do it.